# Component Link is not working

Tags: dynamic-linking

Component link is not resolving after publishing the page(Deployer side)

```xml
<tridion:componentlink pageuri="tcm:131-43782-64" componenturi="tcm:131-56642"
templateuri="tcm:0-0-0" addanchor="false" linktext="test link" linkattributes=""
textonfail="true">
```

1. checked publication target langualge set to jsp.
2. checked page template file extension(jsp)
3. cms side link looks fine after applying link resolver TBB

   `<a href="/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Popups/Preview/Preview.aspx#id=tcm:131-56642" >test link</a>`

Please help me to debug the issue

Comment: Is the target component published too? CM-side it always works, since content doesn't need to published. My guess is that tcm:131-56642 is not published to the same target as your page.

Comment: If you are sure that the Component is published to the target, then you may also want to check that the dropdown on the Component Template (that is rendering the target Component  - tcm:131-56642) is not set to 'Never Link'.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe missing `cd_tags.tdl` in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and the tag declaration, `<%@ taglib uri="cd_tags" prefix="tridion" %>`, at the top of the JSP page?

See: http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/component-link-samples.html

Answer (score 1):

This kind of behaviour can be due to the following things:

1. You missed the page tag declaration element and/or the TDL config (as pointed out by Chris)
2. Your unresolved link is on a Dynamic Component Presentation, and this DCP being retrieved via the Broker API using the ComponentPresentationFactory, not the ComponentPresentationAssembler;
3. your CT is Dynamic and Output Type is set to HTML.
4. your CT is Dynamic and Output Type is set to Java (or Jscripting), but your DCPs are configured to go into the Database instead of filesystem in cd_storage_conf.xml (use REL as the Output Type in this case).

Comment: Hi , i am also getting the same issue, in my case it is working fine in Live but not in staging. is this issue resolved for you ?