# Component Link and Image source are not generating correctly

Tags: content-manager, upgrade, 2013-sp1, linking

We have upgraded our project from "SDL Tridion 2011 SP1" to "SDL Tridion 2013 SP1" with legacy feature.
All went fine and our application was also running properly.
But suddenly after republishing the pages component linking is not generating properly and also image src is pointing to some directory in %Tridion_Home% directory which makes loading image persistent on default.aspx page.

Link looks like :-

```
<a href="/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Popups/Preview/Preview.aspx#id=tcm:15-753"
>Trees and Woodlands</a>
```

Img src look like :-

`<img rc="%Tridion_Home%/Preview/sitename/Images/DSC_0417%20226x152_tcm15-44682-v0.jpg"`

We have dotnet based application and we are using razor templating in it.

We have looked into the similar question [Link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/component-link-is-not-working) but could not get success.

Any help or pointer will be highly appreciated.

The above tag was from the template builder because the component link tag is now coming blank so i tried to debug the issue and i copied the tag from template builder.
Earlier the tag was like:-

```
<li><tridion:ComponentLink runat="server" PageURI="tcm:15-54072-64" ComponentURI="tcm:15-753" TemplateURI="tcm:0-0-0" AddAnchor="false" LinkText="Trees and Woodlands" LinkAttributes="" TextOnFail="true"/></li>
```

But now after publishing the li tag is coming blank and page is publishing to filesystem. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you obtaining this links and url's in the published pages? because they are the preview urls, only for preview and template builder.

Comment: @Raul I have updated the question.Yes,the above tag was from the template builder.

Comment: Template Builder/Preview URLs are always different from what gets published. If you're not getting a link, then it looks like the Server Controls are not properly configured in the web application...

Comment: @Nuno My application was working fine earlier but suddenly after republishing the pages, linking is breaking and image path also changed.

Comment: @Sumit: Check the ASPX page ( open in Notepad++ ) on filesystem and see if the <tridion:ComponentLink /> is present/formed correctly.  Also is the Page containing the "Component" Published ?

Comment: @R.C I checked the aspx page and i did not found <tridion:ComponentLink /> tag in the aspx page after publishing. Although external links are rendering perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you costmized/extended your renderXHTML function(s) at all?

Comment: @Dylan..MarkSaunders We haven't customized/extended any functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue has been resolved after applying the Hotfix Rollup #1 for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.
Also I got Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.dll from SDL to replace with the existing dll and also some config changes in Tridion.ContentManager.config file.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

i also faced similar kind of issue which got resolved after applying 
Hotfix Rollup #1 for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 as suggested by SDL.

Kindly contact SDL for the hotfix or log a ticket in SDL support